# Using GIT to deploy website

Tags: git, githooks

I have followed this excellent write up http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto to deploy code to my server using Git's post-hooks strategy.

I have a **post-update** file that looks like this:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/rajat/webapps/<project name> git checkout -f
```

Everytime I push code to **master** branch, it gets auto deployed. What I want to do now is to make this support multiple branches, so that:

1. git push origin master -----> deploys code to production (/home/rajat/webapps/production)
2. git push origin staging ----> deploys code to staging (/home/rajat/webapps/staging)
3. git push origin test ----> deploys code to test (/home/rajat/webapps/test)

For this, the **post-update** hook needs to understand which branch got updated. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to write a post-update hook which detect the branch name.
See for inspiration:

- "[Writing a `git post-receive` hook to deal with a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7351551/6309)"
- "[Find Git branch name in post-update hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7331519/6309)"

As an example (all those hooks are based on [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
        # Do something
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is add two bare git repos in different locations on my web server; one for test, one for production.  Both repos have post-hooks to checkout to the correct directory. Then I add both as remotes on my (single) local repo.

Using this method I can push any branch to my test remote or my production remote at any time.  Not sure if this is the *right* way but it's worked well for me.