# How to change the source code of minix in a local repository

Tags: git, qemu, minix

I've been wondering how to solve the following problem. I'm currently learning how to modify an OS's source code to my liking, working example being A.S.Tanenbaum's `minix`.

Say I run `minix` with `qemu` and I redirect the ssh port to `localhost:10022` (using `-net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22`), so that I can `ssh -p 10022 user@localhost` to connect to the system that runs on `qemu`.

Now, `minix`'s source code is located in `/usr/src`. I want to have this code locally on my machine -- best in a `git` repository -- and be able to modify it and then push it and build on the virtual machine.

To summarize, I want:

- To have a copy of `minix`'s `/usr/src` on my machine, in a git repository
- To be able to `git push` it from my machine (or anything like that), so that if my changes break the system completely, I can start over from my base image of `minix`

I have tried making `/usr/src` into a git repository that I can clone to my local machine. However, apparently pushing to a non-bare repository is not advisable, and a bare git repository, which doesn't contain any uncommited files, doesn't seem like the way to go.

Also, I would prefer not to brute-force it by just pushing / pulling to another remote.

I would appreciate any hints on how to set up my repositories to create my desired workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host: just one non-bare repository (+ backups).

VM: one bare and one non-bare repository in /usr/src.

Initial setup: create a non-bare repository in /usr/src in VM. Add and commit everything. Clone the not-bare repo to a bare repository somewhere. Clone from bare repo at VM to not-bare at the host.

Workflow: Edit sources at the host, add and commit. Push from host to the bare repo at VM. Pull from bare to not-bare at VM and compile.

Pulling from bare to not-bare can be made automatically using ["remote deploy"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18804552/7976758) hook (post-receive or post-update).