# Synchronize a distant server directory with a local git repositery

Tags: git, ssh, synchronization, git-bare, git-init

I want to synchronize a directory `/home/myproject` of my distant machine with, as source, the directory `D:\myproject\` of my local machine. I would like to use `git` (to also benefit from commits history, etc.)

I did this on distant machine (creation of a bare repository, see also [What is the difference between "git init" and "git init --bare"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861184/what-is-the-difference-between-git-init-and-git-init-bare)):

```
mkdir /home/myproject.git
cd /home/myproject.git
git init --bare
```

and this on local machine (with current directory `D:\myproject\`):

```
git init
git add main.py   # D:\myproject\main.py exists on local machine
git commit -m "First"
git remote add dest root@203.0.113.0:/home/myproject.git    # via ssh
git push dest master
```

It works, now distant server's `/home/myproject.git` is synchronized, but the directory `/home/myproject/` (that should contain for example `/home/myproject/main.py`) still **doesn't exist**!

So I have to do this on the distant server:

```
cd /home
git clone myproject.git myproject
```

and now `/home/myproject/main.py` exists.

Problem: each time I do `git push` on local machine, it's distant server's `/home/myproject.git` which is updated, **and not `/home/myproject/`**.

**Question: how to configure these repositories such that `git push` automatically updates all the files in `/home/myproject` such as `/home/myproject/main.py`, instead of only `/home/myproject.git`?**

Comment: About bare repositories: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7861184/7976758. Using GIT to deploy: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18804552/7976758.

Comment: Thank you @phd, I already read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861184/what-is-the-difference-between-git-init-and-git-init-bare before posting the question, but it did not really help in this precise request, i.e. `git push` updating not only the myproject.git but above all the destination directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easier solution (not requiring a "bare" repository or "post-receive hook" script):

1. On the distant machine, create the destination repository and configure it like this:

   ```
   mkdir /home/myproject && cd /home/myproject
   git init
   git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
   ```
2. On the local machine (from working directory `D:\myproject\`), create the source repository, and push it:

   ```
   git init
   git add main.py
   git commit -m "First"
   git remote add dest root@203.0.113.0:/home/myproject
   git push -u dest master
   ```

   Now `/home/myproject` is updated on the distant machine!

Note: this requires git version >= 2.4. If you don't have this one, and not available in your current distribution [this can help](https://git-scm.com/download/linux): `add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa; apt update; apt install git`.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [tutorial](http://toroid.org/git-website-howto), here is a working solution:

1. On the local machine (from working directory `D:\myproject\`), create the repository:

   ```
   git init
   git add main.py
   git commit -m "First"
   git remote add dest root@203.0.113.0:/home/myproject.git
   ```
2. On the distant machine, create a "bare repository" + the destination directory:

   ```
   mkdir /home/myproject.git && cd /home/myproject.git && git init --bare
   echo -e '#!/bin/sh\nGIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myproject git checkout -f' > hooks/post-receive
   chmod +x hooks/post-receive

   mkdir /home/myproject
   ```
3. On local machine:

   ```
   git push -u dest master        # later we can just do: git push
   ```

Now `/home/myproject` is updated on the distant machine!