# How can I clone a git repository on a server automatically to another folder on every commit

Tags: node.js, git, express, ubuntu

I have a simple express.js-powered API running on an ubuntu server with pm2. The `server.js` and the other files are in `/var/www/node/api/`.

On this server, at `/srv/git-repos/api.git/` is my git repository, where I commit new changes from my local machine.

The Question is, is it possible, that every time I commit new changes to the server, it recognizes this, and clones my repository to let's say `/var/www/node/api-dev/`(which will then be available at dev.example.com, this could be made possible with nginx, so there is no problem) and restarts my pm2 instance with `pm2 restart api`.

Because then I would test, if my changes work on the server, and when they do, I just can copy the content of `/var/www/node/api-dev` to `/var/www/node/api` manually.

Or is there another, better workflow? It's just a small API on which I will make many changes because I want to develop it for the needs of my frontend.

Thanks for your answers and suggestions, I hope it's understandable what I want to archive.

Comment: Just create a bash file

Comment: @SmartManoj this answer doesn't help me, I asked *how* to do this

Comment: I think you'd better create a 'git worktree' and each time, do a 'git reset --hard sha_of_last_commit' (that will be way quicker than cloning)

Comment: And run your script in a git hook: https://githooks.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using GIT to deploy website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804552/using-git-to-deploy-website)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+to+deploy+hook

Answer (score 0):

```
git commit
git clone <repo> ../api-dev
pm2 restart api
```

Save it as c.sh and run with ./c.sh or add to your .bashrc

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I do currently. Isn't there an option to automate this process?