# Git push send parallel copy to test server

Tags: linux, git

I search the method to copy files to "test" host when I launch the "git push" command.

```
git push   ------- TO REPO --> REPO_SERVER
           \
            \_________ TO DIR --> Host_TEST
```

Git Version: 2.20.1

Comment: Use a [`post-receive` or `post-update` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18804805/7976758) either at the `REPO_SERVER` or create a bare repo at the `test` server. It's called push to deploy: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+%22post-update+hook%22+push+to+deploy, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+%22post-receive+hook%22+push+to+deploy. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387030/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to (re) invent CI/CD.
If you are using GitHub or GitLab as a remote server you can use `Pipelines` (or `Actions` in GitHub).
In there you can define (almost) anything you want to happen after a push, I am assuming your `Host_TEST` is accessible online.

**In case you are running your own git server**
You can implement "push to deploy" using the `post-receive` hook. Hooks are scripts that are placed inside `.git/hooks` and executed at a precise phase of a git command. you can find several example implementations in `.git/hook`. See here for more information: [Setting up Push-to-Deploy with git](https://krisjordan.com/blog/2013/11/02/push-to-deploy-with-git)

**In case you don't have access to your own git server**
You can use the `pre-push` script on your local machine, ***BUT THIS IS A BAD IDEA***
This hooks is executed after you execute `git push` but before `git` actually pushes anything.  If your script fails (i.e non-zero return code) it will not push.
Also, if your script manages to copy but then `git` fails to push you will end up testing code that's not in your repo.

**If all this sound way too complicated**
You can create a bash function that does both operations and add it to your `.bashrc`.

Here is an example:

```
push_copy() {
   if git push
   then 
      # Copy for command here: scp ...
   else
     echo "Failed..."
   fi
}
```