# Best practice - Git + Build automation - Keeping configs separate

Tags: git, build, automation, gruntjs, bitbucket

Searching for the best approach to keep my config files separate, yet not introduce extra steps for new developers setting up their environments.

I am guessing a submodule would suffice to do the job, but then how would I switch configs seamlessly depending on the task at hand, aka pull in DEV config regularly, pull PROD branch of config repo during build?

Needs to be:

- Easy and painless for new devs.
- PROD config files should only be accessible to select users + build user.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just edited the answer to add a way to detect the branch in which a script is executing itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is called **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11961257/6309)**, and it allows you to declare, in a `.gitattributes` file (and only for your config files type) a **smudge script** which will *automatically on checkout*:

- combine a config file *template* file (`config.tpl`)
- with the right config file value (`config.dev`, `config.prod`, ...)
- in order to produced a non-versioned config file (private file)

[image: Smudge filter]

See "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)":

```
echo '*.cfg.tpl filter=config' >> .gitattributes
git config --global filter.config.smudge yourScript
```

With that approach, you don't need submodules, but you can generate as many config file you need depending on your environment, like for instance your branch:
A bit like in "[Find Git branch name in post-update hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332273/6309)", your smudge script can find out in which branch it is currently executing with:

```
#!/bin/sh
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I ended up going the route of storing configs separately and puppetizing my setup, this is still great info and I never knew about this feature before.

Comment: Is there no need for the argument name `filter=` at `echo '*.cfg.tpl config'`, i.e., making it `echo '*.cfg.tpl filter=config' >> .gitattributes`.

Or is `filter` the default argument Git looks for in config if no argument name is provided in `.giattributes`?

Comment: @ToJo Good point, thank you. I must have missed it 6+ years ago. I have edited the answer accordingly.