# Why there are something modified after git clone?

Tags: git, github

I have a project using github git ignore template. https://github.com/github/gitignore When I git clone this repo and didn't modify anything, git status still shows me there is a file modified. The worst thing is that even use git checkout, the file still exist with modified status.

```
modified:   OpenCart.gitignore
```

This problem will cause my git submodule does not work well. How to fix it?

Update:
This is what git diff shows:

```
diff --git a/OpenCart.gitignore b/OpenCart.gitignore
index f317912..c673f1f 100644
--- a/OpenCart.gitignore
+++ b/OpenCart.gitignore
@@ -1,7 +1,10 @@
-.htaccess
 config.php
-download/
-image/data/
-image/cache/
-system/cache/
-system/logs/
+admin/config.php
+
+!index.html
+
+download
+image/cache/*.jpg
+image/cache/data/*
+system/cache
+system/logs
```

But I didn't modify this file and `ls` command cannot list this file.

Comment: What is the output of `git diff`? (Can you recognize what kind of changes are present?) What is the output of `git config -l`? (Do you notice any filters or anything else unusual?)

Comment: Maybe you have a smudge filter? See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for your gitignore file to be taken into account, you should rename your `OpenCart.gitignore` as `.gitignore`.

Generally, a file "modified" on checkout is because of `git config core.autocrlf` being set to true.
See "[git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/6309)".

---

For more advanced content transformation, look for a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822928/6309), a smudge script which, on checkout, would modify a file.

```
git config -l | grep smudge
```

[image: smudge]

Comment: what does `filter.media.smudge=git-media-smudge %f` mean? Actually it is created by github app.

Comment: I remove it, but the problem still exist.

Comment: @Ciel does the issue still persists if you re-clone the repo? (while making sure that `git config -l | grep smudge` is empty)