# How to prevent file in one branch from being *added* to any other branch during a merge?

Tags: git

Suppose that, while on some branch `branch-X` I add and commit a certain file, `foo.txt`, and that this file is not being tracked by any other branch in the repo besides `branch-X`.

I want to tell `git` that, whenever `branch-X` is merged into *any other branch* in the repository, the file `foo.txt` should never be added.

I have tried doing this by, e.g., setting the following line in the appropriate `.gitattributes` file

```
foo.txt merge=ours
```

...but the file keeps getting added whenever I run

```
git checkout otherbranch
git merge branch-X
```

I guess that the issue here is that there's no real "conflict" between the file `foo.txt` in `branch-X`, and "no file" in `otherbranch`, so the merge strategy does not need to come into play.  (BTW, *this is why this question is not a duplicate*, AFAICT: all related questions I've found refer to the case of conflicting files that exist in *both* branches of the merge, and the answers given to those questions don't seem to work for the case I'm presenting here.)

Also, at least in cases where the merge is a fast-forward, no new commit is done, so it's no use to run `git-merge` with the `--no-commit` option in the hopes of explicitly removing `foo.txt` from the index.

I imagine that the mechanics underlying what I'm trying to do here would require translating the command

```
git merge branch-X
```

into the sequence

```bash
git branch branch-X-no-foo branch-X
git checkout branch-X-no-foo
git rm foo.txt
git commit -m 'pay no attention to the man behind the curtain...'
    # or maybe
    # git commit -C HEAD --amend
git checkout otherbranch
git merge branch-X-no-foo
```

I suppose I that I could write a script to wrap this sequence into an easy-to-type command, but I thought I'd ask if there's a better approach.

Comment: Isn't this `git merge --no-commit branch` followed by `git rm --cached foo.txt` followed by `commit`?

Comment: @matt: as I pointed out in my post, that may work unless the merge is a fast-forward; in the FF case there's no commit.  (I suppose that in the FF case, one could do `git rm foo.txt` followed by `git commit -C HEAD --amend`...  I need to look into this.)  At any rate, it seems that I'll have to write some scripts to automate this...

Comment: Okay, `git merge --no-commit --no-ff` then.

Answer (score 1):

One actual workaround to avoid having to deal with merge driver is to:

- version a `foo.txt.tpl` template file
- version a `foo.txt.values` with values for the right branch(es)
- version a script able to detect the current branch and generate (or not generate, depending on the current branch) the right foo.txt file on checkout (smudge script)

See this [example of **content filter driver**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822928/6309):

[image]

<sub>(Picture from "[Customizing Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)" from the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en))</sub>

That way, you don't have to deal with merge at all.