# Git Track File Existance Only, Not File Contents

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there any way to tell Git to track a file's existence, but not to track the content of the file? I would like Git to create a file if it doesn't already exist when git pull is run, but to otherwise ignore the file.

This would be highly useful for error_logs ect in a web-app I am developing.

Comment: Maybe you can use [`git annex`](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) for this? I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A native way to do this (beside [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/)) is to:

- track a file *template*
- version a script which is able, on checkout, to generate the file from the file template (if the file doesn't exist yet): that file won't be versioned and will remain private.
  The script knows how to generate that file or from where to copy it.
- declare in a [`.gitattribute` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822928/6309)**: a **`smudge`** script which will run automatically on checkout and will reference the script mentioned in the previous point.

[image: http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0702-tn.png]

<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)" " from the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en))</sup>