# git-flow finish release - selective merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow

We've recently started using `git-flow` in our company, and we've came across the following issue:

We have a `DEV_MODE` boolean that controls the level of logging in the app, we want the develop branch to always have `DEV_MODE=true`.
However, when releasing a version we change the `DEV_MODE` to `false`.

When I do finish-release in `git-flow`, it'll merge the `DEV_MODE=false` into the develop branch.

I there a hook I can use to prevent this, or maybe a way to tell git how to merge files from release branches to develop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid the merge issue entirely by versionning a file "template", with a placeholder value in it:

```
DEV_MODE=@devmode@
```

You can then declare a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) (in [a `.gitattributes` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) in order to automatically generate the right content for that file on checkout, [depending on the branch currently checked out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822928/6309).

[image: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/book/08-customizing-git/images/smudge.png]

<sup>(image shown in "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script can use this to detect the current branch:

```
#!/bin/sh
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds exactly what I want. quick question - will the 'git config --global' command get shared between my fellow workers or will it be only for me?

Comment: @marmor a git config (global or otherwise) is always local (local to the repo, local to the user or local to the machine). It is never shared.