# Exclude some files from inter-branch merges in git

Tags: git, merge

I have a couple of files (a pom.xml and an appengine-web.xml (GAE config file)) that I want to keep in different states in different branches of the same project.

Similar questions have been asked before and two of the solutions I've seen suggested before are:

- `git merge --no-commit from-branch`, and,
- Create file `.gitattributes` in the same dir, with this line: `filename.ext merge=ours` (paraphrasing)

Both these only protect the file in the current branch from merges if there is a conflict during merge. In case of an FF merge, the version in the current branch gets overwritten. I want these files to not be overwritten even in the case of an FF merge.

Isn't there a way to protect the version in the current branch from ever being overwritten by a merge, unless invoked by a file-specific command?

I am currently resorting to not checking in the per-branch files, putting them on the stash and then restoring from there when I come back to the branch. Is there a more efficient and less fault-prone way?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to:

- *not* track `pom.xml`
- track `pom.xml.master` and `pom.xml.mybranch`: that way, any merge won't affect them, since they are named differently.

Then, you can version and track:

- one pom.xml per branch (with a naming convention following said branch).
- a script able to take the right `pom.xml.<abranch>` file depending on the current branch, and generate the `pom.xml` file (which remains untracked, private)
- a `.gitignore` which ignores the resulting generated `pom.xml` file
- a `.gitattribute` declaring a smudge content filter (see below)

The generation of the actual `pom.xml` is automated through a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tumAc.png]
<sup>(image from ["Customizing Git - Git Attributes"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)"))</sup>

Once you declare that content filer driver in your local config, it will automatically, on `git checkout`, generate your `pom.xml` file for you.
See a complete example in "[Best practice - Git + Build automation - Keeping configs separate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822928/6309)".

Repeat the same idea for the `appengine-web.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll study this and try it out, seems like it could be the solution for me.

Comment: +1 - that "smudge filter to make an untracked file" trick is pretty nice, if you don't have a build system that can do it for you (or don't want to assume or invoke one)

Comment: Confused. Does the smudge filter get the name of the file to be "smudged"? Does a clean filter also have to be defined? Can smudge filter be run on a file that's not tracked? Created the branch-specific files, but not getting anywhere with writing out a pom.xml (in my case I simply need to copy pom.xml.<branch-name> to pom.xml).

Comment: @markvgti Does the smudge filter get the name of the file to be "smudged"? No: it is applied to what you define in your `.gitattributes.` (in your case: `pom.xml.* filter=my_smudge_filter`) "Does a clean filter also have to be defined?" No: you don't modify any tracked file, so you don't have to clean any track file. You use the smudge to generate an untracked file.  "Can smudge filter be run on a file that's not tracked?": No, hence my suggestion to track `pom.xml.xxx`, and generate the actual `pom.xml` from there.