# Is there a Git equivalent to Plastic's hidden_changes.conf?

Tags: git, ignore, plasticscm

Plastic defines the *hidden_changes.conf* file as such:

[Hiding changes with hidden_changes.conf](https://docs.plasticscm.com/book/#_hiding_changes_with_hidden_changes_conf)

> Just like you sometimes need to ignore private files with ignore.conf, there are scenarios where you don’t want Plastic to detect changes in specific files because you don’t want to accidentally include them in the next checkin. This can happen if you need to adjust config files for a debug session or alter some source code for whatever reason, but you don’t want to checkin those temporary changes.
>
> hidden_changes.conf helps achieve that.

generally we used this file in Plastic to supply a list of files that always needed to be present (mostly "defaulted" settings and configurations), which were expected to be changed per developer (as needed), but should never be checked back into source control.

Does Git provide a similar file/feature? I am only aware of the .gitignore file and that obviously does not serve the same purpose.

Comment: With Git you can just change whatever you want and can selectively choose to commit or not commit it. You don't really need a feature that prevents you from accidentally committing changes.

Comment: .gitignore is used for the same purpose. Except you cannot “alter source code” (since that is presumably already tracked and .gitignore won’t work). For something beyond that see the [precious files proposal](https://lore.kernel.org/git/pull.1627.git.1703643931314.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/#t)

Comment: No, git doesn't support this directly that I'm aware. You can use `git add -i` to selectively add chunks to the index rather than all changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undo git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195861/undo-git-update-index-assume-unchanged-file)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353292/git-update-index-assume-unchanged-by-default, which suggests another solution for this sort of issue.

Comment: No. This is better handled with improved configuration management. Have default config files and put local overrides in separate files or environment variables. This will benefit both developers and your users; there's no risk of your local changes being overwritten.

Comment: With git hooks, you can customize the script to exclude specific files or parts of the changes on `git commit` while keeping changes. Smudge and clean filters can also serve the purpose to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

No, [Git doesn't support ignoring changes to tracked files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files).  The Git FAQ says this:

> Git doesn’t provide a way to do this. The reason is that if Git needs to overwrite this file, such as during a checkout, it doesn’t know whether the changes to the file are precious and should be kept, or whether they are irrelevant and can safely be destroyed. Therefore, it has to take the safe route and always preserve them.
>
> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

However, the FAQ mentions the recommended approach for config files and similar types of situations:

> If your goal is to modify a configuration file, it can often be helpful to have a file checked into the repository which is a template or set of defaults which can then be copied alongside and modified as appropriate. This second, modified file is usually ignored to prevent accidentally committing it.

Comment: Okay so if I understand this correctly, the idea is to create and commit these files in their "default" state, then immediately add them to the .gitignore in a second commit, so any further changes to those files will not be committed. Is that correct?

Comment: No.  `.gitignore` doesn't affect tracked files in any way.  You add the files in a default state in a place other than the one you normally want them (e.g., `defaults/foo.cfg` and ignore the location you want them to be normally (e.g., `config/foo.cfg`).  You can also add a script to modify the template or copy it into place, merge changes, etc.