# Using a git pre-commit hook to exclude non-meaningful changes

Tags: git, githooks

I've got a large collection of files I want to keep in git. Each of these files has a header that can be automatically updated containing time-stamps and other details about when the file was last exported (they're code files exported from a specific tool)

Since the changes to the header aren't particularly meaningful on their own, I'd like to use a git pre-commit hook to exclude files where there's no change in the actual body of the code. What's the recommended way for me to perform a comparison and discard files where only the first n lines have changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach (than trying use a hook) is:

- either to not track those files if they can be regerated
- or track them, but use a content clean filter driver to restore their content if the changes detected are not significant enough.

For the second option, you need a script able to detect if the git diff includes other changes that in the header. If not, the script would perform a git checkout -- afile, in order to restore its content to HEAD (discarding any local changes).

The restoration of the file through that script is automated through a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tumAc.png]
<sup>(image from ["Customizing Git - Git Attributes"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)"))</sup>

Once you declare that content filer driver in your local config, it will automatically, on `git commit`, inspect your file for you.
See a complete example in "[Best practice - Git + Build automation - Keeping configs separate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822928/6309)".

Comment: Option 2 work better in this case (the files are source code exported from a particular tool (DataStage) that includes a header with export date / time.