# How to trigger post-receive hook with non-master branch

Tags: git, workflow

I have two remote repositories being managed by my local git repository:

- origin
- stage

I have a post-receive hook for each remote:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/REMOTENAME --git-dir=/var/repo/REMOTENAME.git checkout -f
```

However, when I push non-master branches, the work tree does not get updated.  For example, if I have a branch called 'test', I would run:

```
git push stage test
```

and I would not see any changes on the remote's work tree.

If I run:

```
git checkout master
git merge test
git push stage master
```

I do see the changes on the remote's work tree.

My goal is to be able to use a workflow that allows me to separate development on multiple branches and push non-master branches to stage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a branch to checkout in your post-receive hook.
The default branch used is master. This is why the behavior is different when you push a non-master branch.

The branch can by known in a separated shell command.
`branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $1)`. (Source [Git branch in a hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331519/find-git-branch-name-in-post-update-hook) )

Then, add `$branch` at the end of your checkout command.